# Statistical Problems with Three-Dimensional Frequency Tables in R

Tags: r, frequency

I am working with a Three-Dimensional Frequency Dataset now, and the three dimensions are subjects, choice and conditions.  I wanna compute the frequency of different choice of different subjects under different conditions. But now what I have done showed the frequency of the choice under all conditions not a single condition.

The dataset:
[image]

What I have done:

```
freq1 <- table(selectdata3[which(selectdata3$keypress == 1),])

y<-xtabs(~sub_id+keypress+cond,data=selectdata3)
y

x<-xtabs(~sub_id+keypress+cond,data=selectdata3)
prop.table(x,1)
```

The results:
[image]

Therefor I wanna figure out how to compute the frequency under every condition?

---

Sorry, I think I didn't describe my question explicitly. Now I have gotten the frequency of what I want,  but I need to calculate the proportion of the choice 2 of evey single subject under every condition. And I'm new here, thanks for 2 friends who helped me fixing my faults, thanks very much~

Here is my answer, I am not sure if it's right:

```
x<-xtabs(~sub_id+keypress+cond,data=selectdata3)
prop.table(x,c(1,3))
```

It seems works~~

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Instead, you can upload data with `dput` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example